# Finding the date diff between all pairs of dates in an array without using two loops

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a huge array containing dates as its element:

```
arr = ['01/01/2020', '15/11/2021', '05/07/2018', '01/03/2020', '10/10/2022', '07/02/2015', ....]
```

I would like to find the date difference between all pairs but using two loops has a time complexity of **O(nˆ2)**. I think there should be a faster way, maybe using a Dynamic Programming approach.

Could you solve it in a faster way?

Comment: If you plan on using NumPy, you can compute what you are looking for in a theoretically less efficient, but practically faster way using vectorized operations.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You could use a clever algorithm if you were looking for a particular value (e.g., the smallest date difference). What you are asking for is the date difference between all pairs. By definition, you are asking for O(N^2) results, therefore you must do O(N^2) operations.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible.

If you have n dates, there are (n<sup>2</sup> - n)/2 unique combinations of two dates. So there will be (n<sup>2</sup> - n)/2 outputs.

There is *no possible way* to generate (n<sup>2</sup> - n)/2 outputs in fewer than (n<sup>2</sup> - n)/2 steps.

There are various ways to optimize the individual calculations, but you can't avoid generating the outputs.